# Numbers in Section Headers using book class

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I am using the `book` class for a document, but I would like to add the section numbering to every section heading, similar to how `report` works.

For example, the document defined by

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}

\begin{document}
   \chapter{A Chapter}
      \section{A Section}
         \subsection{A Subsection}
\end{document}
```

Appears as

> Chapter 1
>
> A Chapter
>
> A Section
>
> A Subsection

I would like it to appear as

> Chapter 1
>
> A Chapter
>
> 1.1 A Section
>
> 1.1.1 A Subsection

On a side note, these sections are numbered correctly in the table of contents.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your request is actually the default setting for `book`, at least for section levelling down to `\subsection`. Running your example I see the section etc. numbered as 1.1, 1.1.1 ... etc. You're using something that prevents this. However, `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}` in the preamble should work, meaning that even `\subparagraph` will be numbered then

Comment: Thanks, I had added the titlesec package, which supressed it.

Comment: `titlesec`, .... sigh ........

Comment: I don't recall why I had `titlesec` (removing it did nothing). Is there a particular reason that I should avoid it in the future?

Comment: It's not my favorite package, to be polite ;-) (And the downvote to your answer is not by me, however)

Answer (score -1):

I had accidentally included a package (`titlesec`) that caused the behavior that I did not want. Thank you Christian Hupfer for pointing this out.